# Prevent text being treated as a link

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have some text I want to put on a page that looks like [[:upper:]]. Unfortunately this is being interpreted as a link.

How do I prevent this?

This is for Sharepoint for Office 365.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a Sharepoint guru will contradict me but I think the default behaviour (Wiki-type pages) is to always interpret '[[' as 'link following'.

I found a workaround is to insert a 'hair space' (`&#8202;`) between the two left square brackets.

Edit:

Or even better, just put a '\' in front of the [[ and ]]. For example:

```
\[[:upper:\]]
```